# How do I view Visual Studio BuildLog.htm files without cutting and pasting into an external browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

This may or may not be specific to VS2005 (as that is the version I'm referring to for this question).

I find often the case is that I see this in the Output panel inside Visual Studio

```
2>Build log was saved at "file://c:\\vsdll_example\MyExecRefsDll\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
```

Now, since that looks and smells like a URL, I would have thought that I could simply left mouse click on it, or left mouse double-click on it, and a browser window of some sort would be displayed. No, that doesn't work.  So, to view it, I have to cut and paste the "file://bla/bla/bla" part into an external window.

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio to allow me to browse to that file directly, or view it inside Visual Studio IDE, or something to that effect, without the extra fiddling with cutting and pasting? Or is there some type of keybinding I'm not aware of?

Thanks,
bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down Control while clicking on the link. It should show up in the editor.

Comment: Thanks kmort. That does the trick. I tried to mark the up arrow next to your answer as "This answer is useful" but I got the ever so helpful message of 
"Vote Up requires 15 reputation". Sigh.